# What can increase performance of WebSQL on iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, cordova, web-sql

I have PhoneGap app running on Android and iOS, it is using WebSQL. One table has 10 columns and about 350 rows. When I run simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name_column
```

Now this runs pretty good on Android - it takes about 2-3 seconds to execute. But on iOS devices - e.g. iPhone 3G - it takes about 30 seconds and that is unacceptably slow.

Is there any way how to make this run faster on iOS ? Or what would be other way how to accomplish this functionality ?

Comment: Is 2-3 seconds to sort 350 rows on one column really considered pretty good for WebSQL?

Comment: It might be faster to bring everything back and sort it yourself with javascript

Answer (score 0):

have you tried putting an index on that column? http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: Yes, but it seems that WebSQL implementation on iOS is terrible. So I have end up dropping WebSQL support and using good ol' JSON :-(

Comment: I've got a table of about 20 fields where most users will never have more than 20 records. Would it still make a big improvement to add an index?